# Apache reverse proxy to application on tomcat with 8080 port gives wrong URL in response header

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have Apache (2.2) server with below configuration for reverse proxy to application running on tomcat(6) on 8080 port.

```
....  
ServerName ext-domain  
ProxyPreserveHost On  
ProxyPass  /myapp http://int-domain:8080/myapp  
ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://int-domain:8080/myapp  
....
```

When I access below URL from browser

```
"http://ext-domain/myapp"
```

I get below URL replaced in browser address bar.

```
"http://ext-domain:8080/myapp"
```

And apache access log says...

```
"GET /myapp HTTP/1.1" 302 421 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"...
```

How to avoid this port 8080 insertion in response URL?
Can someone help on this? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Update ProxyPassReverse as below.

```
     ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://ext-domain/myapp
```

Refer: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html#usage

Answer (score 1):

OK, the old answer is incomplete. **The culprit is: ProxyPreserveHost on**. You hardly ever need this clause.

The initial configuration template should therefore be:

```
....  
ServerName ext-domain  
ProxyPass        /app  http://int-domain:8080/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /app  http://int-domain:8080/myapp
....
```

The 302 response that startles you is generated **by the backend**. You've told backend the header `Host: ext-domain`, this is the effect of `ProxyPreserveHost`, so backend wants to be nice and obedient and if it need to give you 302 redirect it also uses the same `ext-domain` as a *convenience* to you. Backed knows on which port you connected, so it tries to use the same port as a *convenience* to you. If it's not a convenience, then don't use `ProxyPreserveHost` in the first place, it's the cleanest and least confusing solution to the problem. Most applications (not all) will not require `ProxyPreserveHost`, but use the usual `X-Forwaded-xxx` headers.

The 302 processing is roughly like this:

- `HTTP 302 http://ext-domain:8080/app/foo` is generated by the backend
- Apache checks the configuration for any `ProxyPassReverse xxx http://ext-domain:8080/app`
- if matching, Apache continues with `HTTP 302 xxx/foo` (**this step doesn't happen in your case**)
- if xxx is not a full URL, it's expanded with the usual `ServerName` and similar (so the full meaning of `ProxyPassReverse /app42 ...` is for Apache to say `302 http://ext-domain/app42`)
- Apache also knows that browser talks to Apache's port 80 so it will not misdirect a browser to 8080 unless you tell it to explicitly with a misconfigured `ServerName`.

Comment: Ho NO.  removing ProxyPreserveHost on was a bad idea.  I am running my mmonit server in a docker container and if I remove that flat, my url becomes http://192.168.2.37:8080/index.csp.  This is not what was expected.

Comment: I would apply an additional `ProxyPassReverse /  http://192.168.2.37:8080/` to workaround that weird "feature" of the application (I mean a weird redirect). And the problem is?...